# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following - Oracle12c

Tags: sql, oracle, dbvisualizer

Using DBVisualizer to execute Oracle queries

```
BEGIN 
FOR counter_var IN 1..50
LOOP
INSERT INTO customers VALUES (counter_var,"Yash","Pune",0,0);
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Getting below error: (Attaching screenshot for a reference)
[Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 4, column 59:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
;
[Script position: 99 - 100]
[image: SQL Error]

If I used a single quote still get the same error.[image]

Let me know if we can use any other approach to insert multiple records in Oracle 12c

Comment: use single quotes around your strings, not double-quotes.

Comment: If I used the single quote then also it throws same error

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that:

```
insert into customer 
select level, 'Yash', 'Pune', 0, 0
from dual
connect by level<=50;
```

And one thing to keep in mind: please write the list of columns to insert into, so that that insert won't fail in the event when someone adds a column to the table you are inserting into.
Otherwise, I can't figure why your code failed. Like you had some strange character or so...
Normally, in Oracle SQL and PL/SQL, literal strings are enclosed by single quotes, not by double quotes.

Comment: It is about **double quotes** (to help you figure it out).

Comment: Hi Bogdan, the pasted query worked for me, Thanks